# C# The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Tags: c#, namespaces, key, controls

Here is my code.

```
namespace TextRPG1
{
   public class Program
   {
      private bool nonyn = false;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         //Introduction
         Console.WriteLine("Welcome to TextRPG By AgentMcBride.");
         Console.WriteLine("You can exit at any time by hitting the ESC key!");
         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to begin!");
         Console.ReadKey();
         Console.WriteLine("Great! Lets begin!");

         //Backstory
         Console.WriteLine(" BACKSTORY: You are a peasant trying to work his way through the castle to save the princess.");

         //Inventory tutorial
         Console.WriteLine("INVENTORY: You will pick up items along the way to help you save the princess.  When encountering an item, the program will ask you y or n.  Type y to collect the item.  Note: You can only store 5 items at a time in your sack!");
         Console.WriteLine("Lets try picking up an item!");
         Console.WriteLine("You have found an apple!  Would you like to put it in your sack? Type y or n!");

         //Handle the KeyDown event to determine the type of character entered into the control. 
         private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
         {
            // Initialize the flag to false.
            nonyn = false;

            // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard. 
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
            {
               // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad. 
               if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
               {
                  // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace. 
                  if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                  {
                     // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed. 
                     // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                     nonyn = true;
                  }
               }
            }
            //If shift key was pressed, it's not a number. 
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) 
            {
               nonyn = true;
            }
         }

         // This event occurs after the KeyDown event and can be used to prevent 
         // characters from entering the control. 
         private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
         {
            // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event. 
            if (nonyn == true)
            {
               // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
               e.Handled = true;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It keeps giving me the error

"The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'"

where it says System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs

Also the names "key" and "control" cant be found in the current context.

Im new to programming so no hate please!

Comment: Are you sure this is a Windows Forms application?

Comment: `The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'` - This is correct.  The `Forms` class lives in `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a console application, and it looks like you were trying to determine what keys were pressed. The problem is that you are using keypress events from a form application, take a look at the documentation for `Console.ReadKey()`, it may help you find what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit**

Here is one example of how you can use it:

```
   var key = Console.ReadKey();

   if (key.KeyChar.ToString() == "y")
   {
       Console.WriteLine("-- Yes!");
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   else if (key.KeyChar.ToString() == "n")
   {
       Console.WriteLine("-- No!");
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("-- That isn't an option!");
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause here is that you haven't added a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly.  In order to do that do the following

- Right Click on the project and select "Add Reference"
- Go to the Framework section
- Select System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Check your project type. Here is how you can change it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s3awkzkh(v=vs.100).aspx